# Keybindings don't work Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I'm working on implementing keybindings on a panel that listen if the arrow keys are pressed or not.

If they are pressed, they do an action.
My code:

```
private void createKeyBindings(){
        actionMap = this.getActionMap();
        inputMap = this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("a"),
                "pressedUpArrow");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released UP"),
                "releasedUpArrow");
        this.getActionMap().put("pressedUpArrow",
                 new PressedUpArrowAction());
        this.getActionMap().put("releasedUpArrow",
                new ReleasedUpArrowAction());
    }
```

The actions work (when I map them to a button and press the button, it does what the action is supposed to do).

These keybindings are called for my panel (which is a tab in a tabbedpane). I tried both with keystroke pressed UP and just a (to make sure that is not the issue).
I type these keys when the tab in question is in focus.

Any advice?

Comment: please where is output to the GUI, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: in addition to the answer by @Stephen - in the snippet above you are registering the keystrokes with the wrong inputMap: replace this.getInputMap().put(..) with inputMap.put(...)

Comment: Thanks, fixed that but it didn't solve it.

There isn't any output to the GUI. PressedUpArrowAction momentarily just prints an error message. The Action works, because when I bind it to a key (using setAction) it works when pressed.

Comment: a little tired of repeating the same over and over again: read @mKorbel 's comment and **follow the suggestion** (especially the second half)

Comment: The issue was fixed, thanks your suggestion. Was still working in the wrong window when I did the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible cause of your problem is this:

```
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("a"),
            "pressedUpArrow");
```

Shouldn't it be this?

```
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"),
            "pressedUpArrow");
```

The way that you've currently coded it, the `PressedUpArrowAction()` and `ReleasedUpArrowAction()` fire on the press of one key and the release of a different key.

Comment: Yes, the a was just for testing if it wasn't the cause of misusing the Up key.